# Given one list, how do you find where the same values are indexed in a different list?

Tags: python, list, encryption, indexing, knapsack-problem

I am creating a decryption function for the Knapsack algorithm. I am new to Python programming. I need to find where values in one array occur in the other, index those values, set the indexed values to '1', and set the others that did not have an equivalent value in the other list to '0'.

Assume:

```
privkey = [2,3,6,13,27,52]
searchList = [3,6]
```

Since [3,6] from searchList occurs in positions privkey[1] and privkey[2] I expect the code to set those indices to Binary '1' in a new list. So the new values should be newList= [0,1,1,0,0,0].

What I have tried so far is:

```
newList = []
for i in privkey:
if (privkey[i]==searchList[i]):
    newList = append(privkey.index(i)) # should yield newList = [1,2]  
    print(newList)
else:
    print("none")
```

I don't really know how to go about using the indices to set the values in privkey to '1' values. Any help would be graciously appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with list comprehension:

```py
>>> privkey = [2,3,6,13,27,52]
>>> searchList = [3,6]
>>> [int(x in searchList) for x in privkey]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy solution using a list comprehension, but since it requires many membership tests on `searchList`, you should first create a set:

```py
>>> search_set = set(searchList)
>>> [ int(x in search_set) for x in privkey ]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

The test `x in search_set` returns a boolean, which is converted to a 1 or 0 using the `int` function.

If `privkey` has length m and `searchList` has length n, then this solution runs in O(m + n) time and uses O(m + n) space. The solution without a set is O(mn) time and O(m) space, which will be considerably slower for larger inputs.